# A Beginner Puzzle of Static and Non-Static Classes in OOP ( C# )

Tags: oop, class, c#-4.0, static, non-static

A friend of mine (from work) asked me a question.

1. Remove the `static` keyword from the `Dictionary` `Live` from the `Members` class.
2. Don't use `new Members();` to create an instance in `Check(...)` method.

So with these rules, what you have to do for call `Live` from other class like:

```
Members.Live.TryGetValue(signatureFromRequest, out userId);
```

I have this;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Webbing.Session
{
    public class Members
    {
        // THAT Dictionary Live was a static... public static Dictionary...
        public Dictionary Guid, int> Live = new Dictionary Guid,int>();
    }
}
```

and this:

```
using System;
using WcfService.Session;

namespace Webbing.BusinessDb
{
    public class Signature
    {
        public static bool Check(Guid signatureFromRequest)
        {
            bool result = false;

            int userId;

            Members checker = new Members(); // <--------- don't use this
            checker.Live.TryGetValue(signatureFromRequest, out userId);

            if (userId != 0)
            {
                result = true;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

He is saying, "there is way to do it.", but I can't find it and I don't believe there actually is. What is your opinion?

**UPDATE/ANSWER:**
I solved the question with Daniel Hilgarth 's help... Here it is;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

namespace Webbing.Session
{
    public class Members
    {
        // Guid, userId
        public Dictionary Guid, int> Live = new Dictionary Guid,int>();

```
    private static readonly Members __instance = new Members();

    public static Members Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return __instance;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Usage: Members.Instance.Live.TryGetValue(signatureFromRequest, out userId);

Comment: Only thing I can think of would be Reflection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way with the exact syntax you provided.
One possibility would be a singleton, but it would look like this:

```
Members.Instance.Live.TryGetValue(signatureFromRequest, out userId);
```

Note the `.Instance` part.

See [here](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx) for several ways to implement a singleton.

As you can see, now the `Live` property isn't static anymore but the new property `Instance` is...

I guess it will be best to simply ask your colleague what he meant.

Comment: It works! just perfect... Thank you very much Daniel. I will read the article-link that you gave by answer. But please, -to be a quick; Can you explain me the magic with a few words ?